# Delete UITable sections dynamically with commitEditingStyle in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I’m dealing with an issue I can’t work around… I have a table of names, from a DB-array of customers, every customer has a name property among other data members.

I can delete rows within a section successfully, but what I can’t do it's deleting the section (when the last row within that section gets deleted, section must disappear).

I got:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (4), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).

I know the table does some sanity checking behind the scenes of the data and this should match, but I can’t figurate exactly when, before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths? after? When should I update my property and/or dictionary? Should I manage numberOfSectionsInTableView data-source method?

I repeat, for rows deleting it’s working alright, the table moves out the row and gets updated properly. Last row on section is the deal...

I guess I'm missing something, that’s why I’m asking… Couldn’t find any help reading around either.

Thank you all very much!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from the array and updating the tableview)

        //Check if delete was press
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            //Delete row from dataSource
            if let tv = tableView
            {

                customerList.removeAtIndex(returnPositionForThisIndexPath(indexPath, insideThisTable: tableView))
                // Deletes the name of the customer from the customer list array, sorted by name

                fillArrayOfNames()
                //Fill the array of names for the sections-table, creating a dictionary with the name initials
                //updated from the customer list array (below)

                tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) //Crash in this line

                tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dictionaryOfPatientsInitials.count
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var keysFromDictionary = dictionaryOfPatientsInitials.keys.array

        keysFromDictionary.sort(<)
        let keyByOrder = keysFromDictionary[section]
        let arrayInThisSection = dictionaryOfPatientsInitials[keyByOrder]

        return arrayInThisSection!.count
    }
```

Comment: Are your data sources mutable?

Comment: @Sirens Yes it is. It's a var property. Both, dictionary and array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there but you are going to need a way of detecting that a section has vanished, and which one has gone at which point you can call `deleteSections`

Bracket the update section in a `beginUpdate` / `endUpdate` call but do NOT call `reloadData` (See the docs for those methods about it)

```
/**
remove customer from model layer

:param: index index of customer to remove

:returns: return section that was removed or nil if none was
*/
func removeCustomer(index:Int)->Int? {

    var removedSectionOrNil:Int? = nil
    //logic to remove customer, rebuild model and detect if section has gone also
    return removedSectionOrNil

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from the array and updating the tableview)

        //Check if delete was press
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            //Delete row from dataSource
            if let tv = tableView
            {
                tv.beginUpdates()

                let position = returnPositionForThisIndexPath(indexPath, insideThisTable: tableView)
                let removedSection = removeCustomer(position)

                tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) //Crash in this line

                if let removedSection = removedSection {
                    tv.deleteSections(sections:NSIndexSet(index: removedSection) as IndexSet, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                }

                tv.endUpdates()

            }
        }
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code , this *should* work but tableViews can be tricky when doing vanishing sections.

Comment: Thanks, you made my sky clearer, only thing I'm missing now is that I don't actually know if a section was removed or not. I might find a way by noticing the difference in the dictionary keys, but in your method approach I would need the number too... right?

Comment: thats got be the guts of the `removeCustomer` function. Perhaps count customers per section before and after and if count == 0 then return that section number.

Comment: Yeah I'll figure out something, let me work on this. I'll back to rate the answer and post my solution (if any). Thank you very much.

Comment: if you post your code for `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` I can possibly help if you can't figure it for yourself.

Comment: I'm working in a solution, but I would post the code... Hold on.

Comment: Also I added some methods I've been working on just down here.

Comment: Your solution lead to solving my issue. I accept you answer, also check my implementation below. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Warren I am after something similar I have a bounty on my question if you're interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959227/another-solution-instead-of-tableview-reloaddata

Answer (score 0):

I am sitting with a similar issue - however I have approached the problem from a non-programming way.
What I have done is to have two tableviews one that simply list all "Customer" key's to their details. (I use a key in the dictionary which is written to the DB, and a second to list "customers" details - each customer is a section.
I have then used Checkmark in the key table as my editing accessory for the cell in the table. Using the delete option for editing will delete the key and then I then simply remove that dictionary item in this code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete 
            actDict[keyArray[indexPath.row]] = nil
            keyArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            try! writeFile!.addValuesToUserFile(actDict)

        }

    }
```

This works flawlessly for me.
Sorry for the incomplete initial answer