# Another solution instead of tableView.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am calling batch updates(begin/end updates) on a tableView using this code:

```
  let oldImageSet = Set(oldImageArray)
  let newImageSet = Set(self.images)
  let missingImages = newImageSet.subtracting(oldImageSet)

  let missingImageIndexPaths = Array(missingImages).map{NSIndexPath(row: self.images.index(of: $0)!, section: 0)}
  //Array(missingImages).map{NSIndexPath(forRow:newImageUUIDArray.indexOf($0)!,inSection:1)}

  let removedImages = oldImageSet.subtracting(newImageSet)
  let removedImageIndexPaths = Array(removedImages).map{NSIndexPath(row:oldImageArray.index(of: $0)!,section:0)}

  self.tableView.beginUpdates()
  if missingImageIndexPaths.isEmpty == false {
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: missingImageIndexPaths as [IndexPath],with:.top)
  }

  if removedImageIndexPaths.isEmpty == false {
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: removedImageIndexPaths as [IndexPath],with:.none)
  }
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Which is working alright.

**Edit**

This is my tableView section counts and how I have it set up:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 55
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

But now I have another tableView I would like to be able to call this on, But it has 'Sections' so When I use this I get a crash...?

Does anyone know how to use this code on a tableView with sections?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this related to [objective-c] ?

Comment: @MartinR Well I would accept answers also in objC

Comment: Can you post the crash ?

Comment: @AkhileshSharma here  i.stack.imgur.com/5NEkO.png

Comment: Just being curious why are you returning the posts.count under the sections, which means if there are 100 posts there will be 100 sections with 1 row

Comment: Also your number of rows in section is returning 1 every time so it is a possibility that the index that you are trying to access does not exists in the memory. Use the debugger to check the values for the missingImageIndexPaths and removedImageIndexPaths

Comment: I am doing that because I need a header for every cell! I might be mistaken or they're might be a better way! please tell me if you think there is

Comment: @AkhileshSharma

Comment: The exception that is generated is because there is a memory location you are trying to access which doesnot exists. Thats the reason i said in my previous comment that try to debug, I am pretty sure you are trying to insert at indexes which do not exist.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma isn't my problem that I am trying to insertRows, and not insertSections?

Comment: You can use this method `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` of UITableView. it will reload the rows for given index path thus you can reload not the whole tableview but the indexPaths that changed.

Comment: @Ayazmon yep thats what I am looking for, but instead of reload row, its reloadSections I need

Comment: @Jack you can use the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` if you'd like to change only the data in row and let the header stay the same. But if you'd like to change the whole section then `reloadSections:withRowAnimation` should do the trick.

Comment: yep not sure how to set the reloadSections/deleteSections thought... That my main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just apply what you're doing with rows to sections which means changing `IndexPath`s to `IndexSet`s. `IndexSet` can be initialized with an array of `Int`s where each `Int` represents a corresponding section.

```
  let oldImageSet = Set(oldImageArray)
  let newImageSet = Set(self.images)
  let addedImages = newImageSet.subtracting(oldImageSet)
  // map each image to the section equivalent to its index in `self.images`
  let addedImageSections = Array(missingImages).map{ self.images.indexOf($0)! }
  let addedImageIndexSet = IndexSet(addedImageSections)

  // repeat above process but in reverse to find images that have been removed
  let removedImages = oldImageSet.subtracting(newImageSet)
  let removedImageSections = Array(removedImages).map{ oldImageArray.index(of: $0)! }
  let removedImageIndexSet = IndexSet(removedImageSections)

  self.tableView.beginUpdates()

  // if images have been added insert new sections 
  if !addedImageIndexSet.isEmpty {
        self.tableView.insertSections(addedImageIndexSet, with: .top)
  }

  // if images have been deleted remove sections    
  if !removedImageIndexSet.isEmpty {
        self.tableView.deleteSections(removedImageIndexSet, with: .none)
  }
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Fantastic as always!

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 55
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

replace code with following code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 55
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be good if I didnt want to have a header for each cell! But because I need headers, I have more than 1 section! so My code is correct, its the calling the batch updates I need to changing

Comment: You need to add in posts array and reload that section and use self.tableView.insertSections and self.tableView.deleteSections for reload

Comment: you are inserting rows not sections

Comment: Not sure how to set that up, thats why I posted the question!

Comment: What is posts array?

Comment: its stores the content I download... var posts = [AnyObject]()

Comment: I thing mistake in "cellForRowAt indexPath" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125349/discussion-between-sandeep-kumar-and-jack).